# how to create layout like app language like whatsapp in android?

Tags: android, layout, graphics

Please suggest me how to create layout like app language like whatsapp in android?

I have stuck to create this. [image]I have searched many but not answered. Please help me

Thanks

Comment: It is a bottom sheet.

Comment: @VishnuSDharan i want layout which i have marked

Comment: It is just an icon, the name of the icon is [minimize_rounded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/minimize_rounded-constant.html)